# Deleting Smartsheet Rows with Python

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm working with Smartsheet. It's a good tool for reading the spreadsheet info using the `get spreadsheet` command and retrieving info as JSON. It is also good for getting the cells info.

I can't delete a Row using Row Id. My code follows this structure. Any clue to solve the issue?

```
try:
   smartsheet.Sheets.delete_rows(1817407393163140, [502603992028080004])
   print ('deleted')
except:
   print ('can't delete')
```

Comment: Your delete_rows code looks good. What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: well i tried again with one and two rows.. but i can't delete the rows and the error message is :  <smartsheet.models.error.Error object at 0x76159350> or <smartsheet.models.error.Error object at 0x76159190>  ...   i used the following command from python command line.. >>> sheet = smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet(1817407393163140)       >>> smartsheet.Sheets.delete_rows(1817407393163140, [534283940501514116, 547121432120452996])

Comment: Hmmm...those error messages aren't very helpful. How about the responses you're getting back from the Smartsheet API? An error from the API should look something like:
  "errorCode" : 1006,
  "message" : "Not Found",
  "refId" : "9by9sbwexc7n",
  "detail" : {
    "type" : "row",
    "ids" : [ <row_ids_go_here> ]
  }
}

Comment: So strange i received a succesfull message, but the rows still there, i do need a commit or save procedure after delete row command?.. I will try with postman with curl.

Comment: How are you verifying that the rows are still there? Through another API call to get the sheet or are you looking at the Smartsheet UI? Have you reloaded the sheet in your browser after deleting the rows?

Comment: Yes i use the Smartsheet UI, to see the rows, i refreshed twice at least but the rows still there.. so strange, i'll try with cURL , Postman, to see what happens..

Comment: weird. i recommend reaching out to smartsheet support at api@smartsheet.com so that they can help you figure out what's up.